# Select second product from product list in amazon using Selenium -JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape amazon using selenium.

I have written a script but I am not able to select the product from the list. Every time the length of list retrieved from using selenium is different, is it something wrong with xpath?

Any help would be appreciated.

Steps:

1. Get URL (amazon.com)
2. Search charger
3. select a 10th product from the list.

My attempt so far is below:

```
public class AmazonSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).clear();
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("charger");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-bar-form")).submit();
        driver.findElement(By.id("a-autoid-0-announce")).click();
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        driver.findElement(By.id("s-result-sort-select_2")).click();
        List<WebElement> resultsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
        int size = resultsList.size();
        System.out.println("Size of list = " + size);
        resultsList.get(2).click();
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with selecting the second product? Why do you always use implicit wait? Have you heard about the explicit or fluent wait?

Comment: i was testing the implicit wait , removed it. The problem is i am not able find correct path that i could either populate into a list or select the product as 2nd or 3rd or fourth similar to .get(int). I hope you understand?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- //span[text()='Related searches']  xpath finds the element that contains 'Related searches' span text. Search (ctrl + f) 'Related searches' in the search result. To ensure the page loading one way is showed - there are many different ways.
- Increase wait time to find element and handle with timeout exception - do with following:

public class AmazonSearch  {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).clear();
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("charger");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-search-bar-form")).submit();
        driver.findElement(By.id("a-autoid-0-announce")).click();
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        driver.findElement(By.id("s-result-sort-select_2")).click();
        WebElement we = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Related searches']")));
        List<WebElement> resultsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
        int size = resultsList.size();
        System.out.println("Size of list = " + size);
        resultsList.get(2).click();
    }catch(TimeoutException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Sometime `WebElement`s insertion in `resultsList` is done before loading all charger items in the page and sometime did precisely. First ensure the page is loaded and then insert items. You can user 'Explicit Wait'. Try the following:

```
WebElement we = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
 .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Related searches']")));

List<WebElement> resultsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
```

Comment: it is actually working, i am testing it though if it crashes at any point. would you please explain a bit how `//span[text()='Related searches']` this was found? would be great. I noticed some time it crashes with error message that xpath was not able to be found.